# Convert rows of one table into column of another table. Explanation provided in body

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

Source table:

Student_ID  Subject _ID Subject Marks
1 ------------ 10   ------------ Chem - 82
1 ------------ 11 ------------ Phy ----     89
1 ------------ 12 ------------ Maths - 88
1 ------------ 13 ------------ Eng ---- 80

Target table is like this:

Student_ID  Phy Chem    Maths   Eng
1 ------------- 82--    89 ---      88 ----     80

Note: These "-" are for sole purpose of depicting table. Sorry for the bad formatting.

Comment: After seeing the answer from yogesh, I am actually thinking this can be done. 
Anyways, thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do *conditional* aggregation with `case` expression :

```
select student_id, 
       sum(case when Subject _ID = 10 then marks else 0 end) as Chem,
       sum(case when Subject _ID = 11 then marks else 0 end) as Phy,
       sum(case when Subject _ID = 12 then marks else 0 end) as Maths,
       sum(case when Subject _ID = 13 then marks else 0 end) as Eng
from table t
group by student_id;
```

Comment: Thanks Yogesh. Just curious, can there be other ways to do this ? Like in case we wanted to generalize. Say, when there are many columns to perform such an action. Need your opinion

Comment: @ChangeIsTheGame. . . For just few subjects this method should be fine or relevant else you would need dynamic solution where you have `N . . .` subjects.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to create a dynamic pivot able.

```
CREATE TABLE #T1 (StudentID int,SubjectID INT, Subject varchar(10), Marks int)
INSERT INTO #T1 VALUES (1, 10, 'Chem',82)
INSERT INTO #T1 VALUES (1,11, 'Phy',89)
INSERT INTO #T1 VALUES (1,12, 'Maths',88)
INSERT INTO #T1 VALUES (1,13, 'Eng',80)
INSERT INTO #T1 VALUES (2, 10, 'Chem',80)
INSERT INTO #T1 VALUES (2,11, 'Phy',85)
INSERT INTO #T1 VALUES (2,12, 'Maths',91)
INSERT INTO #T1 VALUES (2,13, 'Mgmt',82)
DECLARE @PivotColumnHeaders varchar(MAX)
SELECT @PivotColumnHeaders =
  COALESCE(
    @PivotColumnHeaders + ',[' + UC.Subject + ']',
    '[' + Subject + ']'
  )
FROM (SELECT Subject FROM #T1 GROUP BY Subject) UC

DECLARE @PQuery varchar(MAX) = '
SELECT * FROM (SELECT StudentID, Subject, Marks FROM #T1 T0) T1
PIVOT (SUM([Marks]) FOR Subject IN (' + @PivotColumnHeaders + ') ) AS P'
EXECUTE (@PQuery)

DROP TABLE #T1
```

Result is:

```
StudentID   Chem    Eng   Maths  Mgmt   Phy
   1         82      80     88   NULL    89
   2         80     NULL    91    82     85
```